# Trocar conexão PostgreSQL para conexão MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, mysqli

Encontrei um projeto feito em PHP OO para ser usado no PostgreSQL com esse aquivo de conexão.

```
   <?php
   class BD {
       public function __construct() {
           pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 user=usuario password=senha dbname=nome_do_BD")
            or die("Erro ao conectar ao servidor");
   }
   public function __destruct() {
    //pg_close();
   }
   }
   ?>
```

Tem como eu mudar esse aquivo para acessar o BD no phpMyAdmin?

Estou usando o WampServer.

Tentei isso, mas sem sucesso:

```
   <?php
      class BD {
         public function __construct() {
    pg_connect("host='localhost' user='root' password='' dbname='nome_do_BD'")
            or die("Erro ao conectar ao servidor");
    }
         public function __destruct() {
    //pg_close();
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Esse link: [TUTORIAL] Conectar site PHP ao banco de dados MYSQL ensina como fazer uma conexão com o mysql! –  Pena Pintada agora   editar

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o phpMyAdmin não tenha nada com isso.

Certamente dá para mudar o acesso de PostgreSQL para MySQL mas vai ter que mudar em vários lugares. A mudança não é tão simples assim.

A primeira mudança é obviamente a conexão, não basta mudar a *string* de conexão, tem que mudar a biblioteca. A mudança começa por usar o [`mysqli_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario", "senha", "banco");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/MySqliConnection.php).

Note que esta variável `$conexao` tem que estar guardada em algum lugar da classe. O código original que estava usando nem era algo que tinha sentido, ele abria a conexão a abandonava ela. Então não me parece um código útil e que vai te ajudar em alguma coisa. Eu procuraria uma fonte melhor.

Outra mudança óbvia é mudar o fechamento. No MySQL é `mysqli_close($conexao);`.

Mas repito, a não ser que esteja colocando código insuficiente, esta classe usando o PostgreSQL foi feita de forma muito ingênua, não aproveite nada dela.

A biblioteca `mysqli` já tem uma forma orientada a objeto, se preferir este estilo de programação. [Dê uma estudada nela](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php). Ou procure uma classe que encapsule toda essa funcionalidade de uma forma melhor. Não tente reinventar a roda. Na verdade se não tiver um bom motivo para criar toda esta complicação, não faça.

Answer (score 0):

Apenas alguns parametros de conexao usando postgree e mysql mudam, por exemplo;
ao inves de colocar `pg_connect`use `mysql_connect`, como você esta usando servidor local (mysql) não há a necessidade de informar a porta, outra diferença na conexão `mysql` é que dentro da informação de conexão você não precisa informar "o que é o que", por exemplo;
ao invés de:

```
 pg_connect("host='localhost' user='root' password='' dbname='nome_do_BD'")
        or die("Erro ao conectar ao servidor");
```

use:

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
```

você tambem pode optar pode usar a conexão com `mysqli`(com i no final mesmo!)

```
mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

perceba que na conexão `mysql` e `mysqli` você não precisa informar o que é `host` e nem o que é `user` como em `postgree`, apenas informe os dados na ordem correta que tudo funcionara.

eu sugiro que use `mysqli` ou ainda melhor, use `pdo`, toda a documentação você pode encontrar na [documentação oficial do php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

e por ultimo mas não menos importante...
para fechar a conexão use `mysql_close()`

Answer (score -1):

Faz o seguinte:

```
$serverIp = "Localhost";
$UserServer ="Root";
$PasswordServer = "Password do respectivo user";
mysql_connect($serverIp,$UserServer,$PasswordServer); 
or die(mysql_error); //Este die(mysql_error); retorna uma mensagem de erro se 
// encaso correr alguma coisa mal
```

[Ve este link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

ou

[Este](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)